# Effect of number of monitoring points on Asian Option Price

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, asian-option

I want to understand conceptually the expected effect of the number of monitoring points used during the average calculation on Asian options pricing and the reason of such effect.

Asian Options depend on the average of the underlying stock price. The average can be computed with all the available stock prices, or one could choose further spaced points effectively decreasing the number of monitoring points.

I have performed some simple MC simulations and if I didn't mess up I see that the price of the Asian option decreases as I decrease the number of monitoring points. Why is that?

Comment: How are you simulating your paths, are you using a GBM?

Comment: Yes indeed @BobJansen I simulate for a given number of steps N. And then I have tried using different number of points as part of the average. Initially using all stock prices and then using a reduced number (spaced equally).

Comment: Hard to say without the code of course, but what happens if you make the volatility zero or really small?